# Questions about Bark scale filter bank implementation for bfcc's

Tags: music, mfcc, cepstral-analysis

I have a few questions regarding the implementation of Bark scale filter banks for the calculation of bark frequency cepstral coefficients.

1) Which filter shape is most commonly used and why?

- Triangular band pass similar to the mfcc's as seen here:- [A Comparative Study of Filter Bank Spacing for
  Speech Recognition](https://maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/spl/publications/papers/merc03_ben.pdf)
- Trapazoidal type shape as seen here:- [Performance Evaluation of Front-end 
  Processing for Speech Recognition 
  Systems](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~wabd002/Technical%20Reports/Technical%20Report%20621_Octavian.pdf) and here:- [Auditory Models for Speech 
  Analysis](http://www.ece.gatech.edu/research/labs/asat/slides/meet-111204/Auditory-lrr.pdf)
- 4th order elliptical bandpass filters used by the [Mir toolbox](https://www.jyu.fi/hum/laitokset/musiikki/en/research/coe/materials/mirtoolbox/MIRtoolbox1.4.1Guide)

2) How should the filters be laid out?

- No overlap with centre frequencies 1 bark apart?
- Half a bark overlap and a length of 1 bark?
- Linearly divided on the bark scale between a predefined frequency range and number of filters? If so how is a suitable number of filters chosen e.g. 40Hz to fs/2

Thanks for any help provided, I've become pretty confused from reading the literature